Flutter converting time to local
Using flutter, I have a date string :
2024-07-13T09:30:00.000Z

I am in UK, so this time should be 10:30
Using
DateTime dateTime = DateTime.parse(event['date']).toLocal(); 

is still returning 09:30 as the time
How can I get the local time please.

use the intl package to format the date and time according to the device's locale and timezone.

Please provide more debugging details. It prints in local time for me. Try pasting void main() { print(DateTime.parse('2024-07-13T09:30:00.000Z').toLocal()); } into dartpad.
